# How to set color scheme (text highlight) in KDevelop 5.6+

Tags: kde, kdevelop

I used to have a color scheme for my KDE applications (previously used in KDevelop 5.3, KWrite and Kate). It is saved as `*.katescheme`

.

[image: KDevelop 5.3.1 selection of kateschema]

.

But after upgrading to 5.6, it does not seems to have this available anymore? There is a color "scheme" selection, but it is a KDE Theme (e.g. Breeze), and do not support `katescheme` extension.

.

[image: KDevelop 5.6]

.

How can I import my color scheme? (this takes quite some time to setup)

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent versions of KTextEditor (thus Kate and KDevelop) use a different JSON-based color theme format.

- The change is described [in this blog post.](https://kate-editor.org/post/2020/2020-09-06-kate-color-themes/)
- The new format and installation paths (you can also use the 'Import' button) are [documented in the Kate manual.](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kate/katepart/color-themes.html#color-themes-json)
- A script `kateschema2theme` to convert old schemes like the one you have can be found [in the KSyntaxHighlighting repository.](https://invent.kde.org/frameworks/syntax-highlighting/-/tree/master/utils/schema-converter)